# UITableView's AccessoryView Being Reused On Multiple Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

I have a TableView that I would like to add a checkmark to a row when it is tapped.  For that, I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSString *selectedCountry = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *Documents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedCountry ofType:@"ppt" inDirectory:@"thepowerpoints"];
        //NSLog(@"%@", selectedCountry);
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            if (self.chosen == nil) {
                self.chosen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [self.chosen addObject:Documents];
             NSLog(@"%@", self.chosen);

        }else {
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [self.chosen removeObject:Documents];
        }

        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}
```

I understand that this is happening due to the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` on the type of Cell.  My question is, what can I change, so that only the tapped rows get the checkmark, and not all of these other cells, once they start getting reused?

Comment: did u try setting the accessoryview to none for the other cells in cell for row at index method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone table view check mark accessory problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985569/iphone-table-view-check-mark-accessory-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code that decides whether a cell should be checked into cellForRowAtIndexPath. Keep a reference to the currently selected index/item and then set the checkmark on that cell. You would set unselected cells to have the accessory view set to none.

Comment: Ok, so are you saying in didSelect, set maybe a BOOLEAN value for that cell, and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath have an if/else statement looking for that BOOLEAN value for a particular cell?

Comment: Don't put the flag on the cell, remember that it's being reused. Put a selected index property on your view controller and set it in didSelect.